# Can mlock() be used maliciously by unprivileged processes to lock up system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory-management

I just learned about [`mlock()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) functions. I know that it allows you to lock program memory into RAM (allowing the physical address to change but not allowing the memory to be evicted). I've read that newer Linux kernel versions have a mlock limit (`ulimit -l`), but that this is only applicable to unprivileged processes. If this is a per-process limit, could an unprivileged process spawn a ton of processes by `fork()`-ing and have each call `mlock()`, until all memory is locked up and the OS slows to a crawl because of tons of swapping or `OOM killer` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that an attacker could cause problems with this, but not materially more problems than they could cause otherwise.

The default limit for this on my system is about 2 MB.  That means a typical process won't be able to lock more than 2 MB of data into memory.  Note that this is just normal memory that won't be swapped out; it's not an independent, special resource.

It is possible that a malicious process could spawn many other processes to use more locked memory, but because a process usually requires more than 2 MB of memory to run anyway, they're not really exhausting memory more efficiently by locking it; in fact, starting a new process itself is actually going to more effective at using memory than locking it.  It is true that a process could simply fork, lock memory, and sleep, in which case its other pages would likely be shared because of copy-on-write, but it could just also allocate a decent chunk of memory and cause many more problems, and in fact it will generally have permission to do so since many processes require non-trivial amounts of memory.

So, yes, it's possible that an attacker could use this technique to cause problems, but because there are many easier and more effective ways to exhaust memory or cause other problems, this seems like a silly way to go about doing it.  I, for one, am not worried about this as a practical security problem.